# How can I access the elements in this JSON parsed hash?

Tags: json, ruby

I am playing with the Github API and trying to access individual elements but am having problems doing so, main ruby file;

```
require 'octokit'

Octokit.configure do |c|
  c.login = 'example_user'
  c.password = 'password'
end

user = Octokit.user 'example_user'

uri = URI.parse("https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/stargazers")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.use_ssl = (uri.scheme == 'https')
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

res = http.request(request)
response = JSON.parse(res.body)
```

I can access for example the first hash no problem with;

```
puts response[0]
```

However if i try to access a key's value I simply get an empty return;

```
puts response[0][:url]
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `JSON.parse` you get stringified keys, thus (**assuming**, that `response[0]` has got the `"url"` key):

```
response[0]['url']
```

Comment: Thankyou @andrey-deineko for opening my eyes to the 'stringifyed' keys fact.

Comment: @jbk no probs! There is a way to convert keys to symbols while parsing json (passing the `symbolize_names: true` option). But be aware that it is not recursive and will symbolize only the "first level" keys, not nested ones